# why is the style added to the header when developing, and when building production, the style is added to the app.css file? Vuejs

Tags: css, vuejs3

npm run build
[image: When build production]

npm run dev
[image: When development]

```
 <style lang="scss">
  .ck.ck-balloon-panel {
    z-index: 2200;
  }

  .ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 400px;
  }
</style>
```

I want when develop and build should be same, is there any way?

---

I seem to have found the problem related to setting css extract properties in vue.config.js
https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract

```
css:{
    extract: false
}

//     Default: true in production, false in development
```

Comment: Please add your code in text, not images, and make a reproducible example from that.

Comment: thanks, i already updated your code in vue component - single file component